# Excel - If A1 has 'xyz', populate B1 with 'www.dictionary.com/browse/a1' where the hyperlink inside B1 refers to xyz instead of simply B1

Tags: excel, dictionary, hyperlink, excel-formula, vba

Intention is to create a dictionary db in excel. Entering a value in A1 should populate B1 with 'www.dictionary.com/browse/A1' - the challenge is that the hyperlink value inside B1 should point to 'www.dictionary.com/browse/A1' (the actual value inside A1)

Comment: Please edit the question according to the rules, it is improve your chances of getting an answer  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the Hyperlink function and concatenate different texts and cell contents in the parameter for the URL. The syntax is

```
=Hyperlink(Link location, Friendly name)
```

Both arguments are text strings. So you can do

```
=Hyperlink("www.dictionary.com/browse/"&A1,A1)
```

Comment: Nice answer, would it result in a smaller filesize if a vba script just built the link for B1 and pasted it in? Triggered by data entry in A1.

Comment: @SolarMike No, it wouldn't. The VBA would take longer to compute than the worksheet formulas (because the formula engine is more efficient than any code anyone can write with VBA) and the file size would probably be bigger with the VBA, since it would contain the VBA code on top of the results of the code, whereas the formula solution would just contain the formulas. But that size difference is really negligible.